# Question on best practices regarding hardcoding variables when working with your own modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to see if there are some recommended best-practices when working with hardcoded variables and modules. I guess, generally speaking, hardcoded variables should go into some kind of main script that contains the main execution of your program, but when it comes to add-on modules that you created on your own, say stuff that contains tons of functions that are best in a separate module for simplicity, I'm wondering if it's better to make everything in modules to be more "callable" from other scripts, or if hardcoded vars are fine even though main programs should be the place to contain them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never hardcode anything, NEVER.

Main programs aren't a place to contain them either, it will just get messy.

Python has modules.

Thus, myself, I use something I call "Python config files".

WARNING: Example does not reflect best programming practises.

```
# config.py
import os

LIBRARY_VERSION = "1.0.0"

MY_VARIABLE = "This is my variable!"
if os.name == "nt":
    DEFAULT_PATH = "C:/"
elif os.name == "posix":
    DEFAULT_PATH = "/home/"
else:
    raise Exception("This library does not support your operating system.")
```

Now that your config is all set, you can use it in code with variable names that have clear explicit meaning, and also are contained where they don't pollute namespace of modules that don't care about them:

```
# main.py
import os

import config

os.chdir(config.DEFAULT_PATH)
print(f"Cool Library {config.LIBRARY_VERSION} is ready!")
```

Python for Python projects is the best configuration language you will ever use.

If you have multiple modules, you can still be reasonable by either having multiple configs, or simply using `LIBRARY_STUFF_VARIABLE_NAME` for example, openGL API has this: `GL_TEXTURE_2D`.

So if your library is `Cool Library`, you can shorten it to `CL`, if there's a module called `Cool Module`, you can shorten it to `CM`, what you get is `CL_CM_VARIABLE`, obviously, pick better names, but if you use short and consistent naming, it will be easy enough to use, and way more readable than random `image.png` and `1` all over the code.

Comment: Thanks Purple Ice. On a side note, does Python allow certain files to be obfuscated the way Javascript does? I think they use "packers"?

Comment: There's such things as pyinstaller but it's for distributing, not obfuscating, anyone can easily "decompile" it as there's tools that can even reverse it back to plain text. source code. Use other programming language if you are worried about it, which I wouldn't be, because it's more important to just have a proper license and disallow common Joe from messing up the code unless they mess with binaries manually, people who can reverse engineer it, eventually will if they need to. Also the final result is pretty big (Hello world is over 5MB and takes a bit to startup for example).